# Obtain OWIN authentication cookie in SignalR

Tags: asp.net-identity, owin, signalr-hub

I am not very familiar with OWIN or ASP .NET, but I am building a site based on the MVC template with Individual User Account configured and I am running to a problem with OWIN cookie middleware. I am using the default `ApplicationSignInManager` as provided in the project template and I also have SignalR hub for some real-time work. Now, in certain conditions, I'd like to log in the user usign the SignalR hub. This code:

```
Get<ApplicationSignInManager>().PasswordSignInAsync(…)
```

Works great in a controller action, because that action will result in a HTTP response with the `Set-Cookie` header which will set the `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie` as expected and further requests will contain it. Since I am returning a value from SignalR hub rather than a controller, I though I'd just obtain the cookie and set it in the hub's client method, as to simulate the controller response.

However I can't seem to figure out how to find the cookie value.

I've looked throught basically everything in the `IOwinContext` and the cookie is nowhere to be found. I can find the logged in `ClaimsIdentity` just fine, not the cookie, thought. I've done some reading and I think the reason why this is is that the middleware that actually sets the cookie is not yet executed at the point I am lookig for the cookie. It might just not be executed at all since in the hub, I don't even know if I am in the OWIN pipeline. I just do this:

```
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>().PasswordSignInAsync()
```

I have attempted to add my own middleware like this:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => { await next; });
```

But this middleware is not being hit at all which makes me think by getting the `ApplicationSignInManager` in SignalR I am creating the `IPrincipal`, yes, but nothing else happens, namely executing the cookie middleware which would set the HTTP response `Set-Cookie` header I am after.

Is there a way I can resolve this and have my user log in in SignalR and then restart the connection on the client so the next `OnConnected` call receives the cookie I set manually and works out the correct `IPrincipal` from it? Can I make the OWIN pipeline run in the hub at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You read it correctly - cookie is not set until the end of the request and response have started.

Anyway, authentication cookie is always set Http-only - meaning JavaScript does not have access to that cookie to prevent client session highjacking. And you are trying to set auth-cookie via JavaScript - that smell with security issues.

I would abandon this idea. Instead log-in user via controller action without any JS involved, then do work with SignalR - easier and more secure.

Comment: Yeah, I am now in the process of reworking the application to use the controller action instead. It makes sense that the cookie is HTTP-only when I think about it. It's a pity, thought, I would've liked it to go through the hub as well. Thanks for your answer!